# NodeJS mutated ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, file, upload

So i wanted to do an app that uploads files.
The client side upload looks like this:

```
upload_btn.onclick = function(){
var f = fileinput.files[0];
if (f) {
    var r = new FileReader(f);
    r.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        if(false)
            alert("name: " + f.name + "n"
                +"type: " + f.type + "n"
                +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
                + "starts with: " + contents
                );

        var json = { fname:f.name, fsize:f.size, binary:contents };

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);
        request.open("POST", "/upload");
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //request.open("POST", upload_form.action);
        request.send( JSON.stringify(json) );

    };
    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
};
```

};

And the NodeJS (server side) code looks like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var post_data = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        post_data += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        uploader.upload(post_data);
    });
```

The Upload function :

```
fs.writeFile( upload_path+"test.jpg", json.binary, "binary", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
        oncomplete();

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(e);
    }
});
```

So basically : when the file is uploaded in a JSON format (client-side), the server receives the chunks of this JSON & join them in a string-variable, then parses the json & get the uploaded file binary data from the parsed json.

the problem here is, when the file is uploaded it is mutated (here, when an image is uploaded, it changes)

here's an example :
[image changed after upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgC21.jpg)

My question, is why? is it the sent binary data that is mutated, or is it a server side problem (node js fs.writeFile bug?)

thanks.

Comment: You need to wait for the write to finish, using a callback.

Comment: @SLaks if u look closely at the code, thats exactly what i did

Comment: But you never actually pass the callback.  You're writing the response too early.

Comment: @SLaks uhm, that was a copypaste mistake, i didnt want to post the whole code, but i corrected it here btw. the problem isn't a callback related thing, i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i think the problem in your Node.js code.
Try to change it to use Buffer:

```
let body = [];

req.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
  uploader.upload(Buffer.concat(body));

  /* use 
      Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  if it is a string */
});
```

Comment: Exactly! you saved my day <3, but can you tell me why a string variable wont work?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Probably it is because JavaScript uses utf-8 charset when http library operate with chunks in ascii bytes. So bad ascii to utf-8 conversion can become special error symbols like "The replacement character "�" (U+FFFD)" and change whole sequence of bytes. You can read more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in the "Invalid byte sequences" paragraph.